# Creation of executable jar with maven, spring boot and repo-less 3rd party libs fail either way

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jar

I am about to deploy my first jar application. So this could be a noob question. To sum it up, my question is how to generate an executable jar with maven and spring, that also holds 3rd party libs (that aren't in a repo) (uberJar) or a jar, that can be run with a given classpath. I tried several approaches live maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin etc.

I started with java because I had to and decided to go with maven and spring boot. My project is based on 3rd party jars, that aren't in a repo because the developers think, the jars are super-secret. That is part of my problem.

So I added the jars to libs/[companyname] and in intellij made a "library" of that folder to include the jars in the classpath(?). While developing, it all works.

Building with maven failed (cannot find symbol). So I added all 80+ 3rd party jars to the pom.xml (system-scope, systempath = ${project.basedir}/libs/companyname). I don't want to create a local repo, because updates of the libs (80+) come in a complete package and could be replaced 1 to 1. Maven builds, but the jar is not runnable given that error message

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`

So I thought, the libs are in the jar for compiling, but not "accessible" from the main class. So I added maven-assembly-plugin to the pom to create an uberJar. This fails after 16 minutes with no error message at the bountycastle package. This seems to be a common problem. I went over to maven-shade-plugin. This creates me an uberJar (60MB) but spring doesn't boot up because it can't find these 3rd party libs. I don't know why.

So I thought to throw away the uberJar-Method and go with the classpath-method, but I don't get it how to do it. In result, it doesn't matter to me if I deploy an uberJar or a jar with classpath-libs. It just has to run. But an uberJar would be nicer.

Okay, here some details of my project and the pom.xml

```
\root
    - \libs
        - \[companyname] <-- 3rd party libs
    - \src
        - \main
            - \....
    - pom.xml
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Libs from official repos -->
    <dependency>
        ...
    </dependency>

    ...

    <!-- These 80+ secret 3rd party libs with no repo -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...<artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.10</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/[companyname]/artifactName-1.0.0.10.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>   
        <resource>
            <directory>libs/[companyname]/**</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>    
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>my main class name / namespace</mainClass>
                <layout>JAR</layout>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I hope somebody can help and explain me how to handle this topic. I read a lot, I tried a lot, and each try ended up with a different error message. That was frustrating.

Thanks guys and girls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you consider setting up an internal maven repository ? The easiest one will be Apache Archival (https://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi):

For Apache Archival, you can actually manually copy your third party libraries into the maven repository.

In your pom.xml, you have to add in the following:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/repository/internal/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: No, I haven't because I didn't know archiva. Just checked and there are docker images available. That's greate because I use a build server. Will this approach get me rid of these "classpath"- or "libs not found"-problems? It looks very promising.

Comment: I used this method when I got a similar problem like you :-)

Comment: So, just fired up a docker container with archiva (thanks to docker), wrote a c# program generating me command lines with groupId/artifactId etc., deployed the artifacts to the new internal repo, updated my pom, compiled, started and was verrry happy. Thanks man, you saved my week and maybe xmas :) Really great. The jar is packaged and starting. As far as I tested, everything works as expected. Really nice. Thanks again.